# Adding a layer in the layer control, remove conflicting layer

Tags: leaflet

In leaflet I'm trying to get a function going that when a user clicks on a certain (image)layer in the layer control panel and it sees that a conflicting layer is on, it turns the conflicting layer off and also turns it off in the layer control panel,

```
map.on('overlayadd', function(e) {
  switch(e.layer){
    case s2: if(map.hasLayer(s3)){map.removeLayer(s3);}
      break;
    case s3: if(map.hasLayer(s2)){map.removeLayer(s2);}
      break;
      default: break;
}

var overlays = {

"A": s1,
"B": s5,
"C": s6,
"D": s2,
"E": s3,
"F": s4,
"G": s7,
};

L.control.layers(baseLayers,overlays,{collapsed:false}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`L.control.layers` does not like being changed inside `overlayadd` event processing function. Simple trick is to put layer manipulation actions inside `setTimeout` processing function with just a slight delay. Then layer will be removed from map and unchecked in layer control.

In your case this would look like:

```
function removeConflictingLayer(layer) {
  switch(layer) {
    case s2: if (map.hasLayer(s3)) {map.removeLayer(s3);}
      break;
    case s3: if (map.hasLayer(s2)) {map.removeLayer(s2);}
      break;
    default: break;
  }
}

map.on('overlayadd', function(e) {
  setTimeout(removeConflictingLayer, 10, e.layer);
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks very much!